# Rails select_tag undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have my problem, kinda solved, but I think its a bit clumsy way, so hope to get a better way, as well as a better understanding whats going on here.

**_form.html.erb:**

```
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

**products_controller.rb:**

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end
```

If user submits form without selecting any of the `select_tag` options he gets `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass` error.

I know that it comes since my `@categories` is `nil`, but I cant figure how to avoid that..?

My final solution, that is working:

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories || Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

But I feel there is a better way. Also I think, that by assigning a default `select_tag` value with `:selected` might work as well, but I couldnt implement it with my knowledge of Ruby syntax...

Comment: When you submit your form `create` method is executed make sure to initialize the `@categories` in `create` method if `@product.save` returns false.

Comment: Oh, that is nice. Thanks for answer. I added     `if @product.save == false
      @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end` to create action and it looks like it works fine. Sad that I cant mark your comment as an answer...

Comment: @dnsh comment works fine, but the answer from @SnehaT is the better way to go, as it gets rid of the need for `@categories` ... preferably you should have as few instance variables as possible for a view, ideally just one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this way of select_tag:

```
select_tag(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), include_blank: "Select Category")
```

Let me know if you face any issue..

Comment: Oh it is even better. I thought that avoiding additional loop would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can go with helper method than using `Category.all` in every view

```
def categories
  Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
end
```

and use it in views

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id,
               options_for_select(categories), 
               include_blank: "Select Category") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as well.

**products_controller.rb:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_select_collections, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create]

  private
    def set_select_collections
      @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end
end
```

After that you should be able to use:

**_form.html.erb:**

`<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), include_blank: "Select one!") %>`